# Retracts preserving De Rham cohomology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have to show an example of a retract $S$ from a $M$ manifold such that $S$ and $M$ doesn't have the same De Rham cohomology. Because of homotopy, I'm looking for a retract that is not a deformation retract but I don't have a clear intuition of how can I choose it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Show that if $Y$ is nonempty then $X \times Y$ retracts onto $X$.

Comment: And then it follows that the De Rham cohomology is different?

Comment: It follows if $Y$ has nontrivial de Rham cohomology, by the Kunneth theorem. Of course it does not follow if $Y$ is, say, a point.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Every non-empty space retracts to a point

Comment: For example, the De Rham cohomology of $S^1$ is $\mathbb{R}$ for $k = 0,1$ right? And the De Rham cohomology of a point is $\mathbb{R}$ for $k = 0$. Am I right?

Comment: They are $\mathbb{R}$ for the $k$ you say and $0$ else, yup. That is to say, $S^1$ and the point have different de Rham cohomologies. But $S^1$ retracts to a point, so that's the desired counter-example.